# Will HttpResponse.Cookies ever be null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httpresponse

I'm writing a unit test for a controller in Asp.net mvc which sets cookies in HttpResponse. 
One of the calls is just `Response.Cookies.Add(someCookie)`, which fails when I call the controller method in my code, since Response.Cookies is null.

But can Response.Cookies ever be null during normal execution of the website?

Comment: You have not posted your unit test code. Normally during the mvc pipeline execution HttpContext is not null. When unit testing, it could be null

Comment: It seems that you did not fake HttpContext. Could you show your unit test?

Comment: Yes, I didn't fake it in this case. But my question isn't about getting it to work. What I want to know is whether I should plan for the case where Response.Cookies is null (ie, should our actual code be doing a null check on that collection). Because if it's never null and ASP.NET guarantees that, then I will just mock it as a new collection everywhere and write my unit tests assuming that this is a given.